# I created a gitlab project from existing repository: how to synchronize with it

Tags: gitlab

I created a git project from a public github project and I would like to get github project new versions: is it possible from gitlab? is it possible from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With command lines, go into you project folder. Type `git remote -v` : you should see a remote repo call `origin` with the address of you repository in gitlab.

Now you can try `git remote add origin_github <url_of_github_project>`. And then `git pull origin_github master` should update your repo from GitHub source to your own GitLab repo.

Comment: I think that these commands work only on my local copy and not on the gitlab project synchronizing it with the github project from where I started.

Comment: Yes, it update your local copy only. But then you just have to `git push <gitlab_repo>` from your local copy to synchronize both GitHub repo and GitLab's one